# MySQL join with two potential field names

Tags: mysql, sql, join, left-join

For a website I'm working on I was tasked with implementing a private messaging system.
My basic scenario here is, there are several message entries in the database, each containing a sender and a recipient. However, the "current user" should be able to see both those messages, as they are both relevant to him.
The problem is, I am only interested in the data of the other user, not my own. But the "current user" can be both the sender or the recipient.

My query down here gets this job done, but it is hardly elegant. I am joining both users, then deciding using an IF which data I should get.

```sql
SELECT
    IF(m.sender = ?, 1, 0) AS isself,
    IF(m.sender = ?, u_recipient.id, u_sender.id) AS other_id,
    IF(m.sender = ?, u_recipient.displayName, u_sender.displayName) AS other_name,
    IF(m.sender = ?, u_recipient_avatar.url, u_sender_avatar.url) AS other_avatar,
    m.text AS text
FROM messages AS m
    LEFT JOIN user AS u_sender
        ON u_sender.id = m.sender
    LEFT JOIN avatars AS u_sender_avatar
        ON u_sender_avatar.id = u_sender.avatarId

    LEFT JOIN user AS u_recipient
        ON u_recipient.id = m.recipient
    LEFT JOIN avatars AS u_recipient_avatar
        ON u_recipient_avatar.id = u_recipient.avatarId
WHERE ( m.sender = ? OR m.recipient = ? )
    AND UNIX_TIMESTAMP(m.timestamp) > ?
ORDER BY m.timestamp ASC
LIMIT 100
```

So basically, my question here is, is there any more elegant way of doing this? Storing the sender/recipient int into 1 single table to be reused in the join? Otherwise, is this a performance hog (joining tables I don't need?). Or should I just take care of seperating these in the application itself?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I would not recommend storing the sender & recipient in a single column. You may want to change your LEFT JOINs to INNER JOINs on the USER table if those are non-null fields. You could also try rewriting the query as two queries: one as the sender and one as the recipient, combined via UNION. Then check the performance and execution plans.

Comment: @AgRizzo - They are not in a single column, but in a single table. (m.sender and m.recipient)

Comment: I thought you were asking if it was a viable alternative to store the value in a single column - per your post :`Storing the sender/recipient int into 1 single column to be reused in the join?`

Comment: @AgRizzo - I see, that is an error on my part, I meant table. I will edit this in a few moments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seeing that I am not allowed to edit the other answer, which was partially correct.
My answer here is based on Ben's, however, with the syntax errors removed.

```
SELECT d.isself, other_id, u.displayName AS other_name, a.url AS other_avatar, text
FROM
(
    SELECT 0 AS isself, m.sender AS other_id, m.timestamp, m.text
    FROM messages AS m
    WHERE m.recipient = ?

    UNION

    SELECT 1 AS isself, m.recipient AS other_id, m.timestamp, m.text
    FROM messages AS m
    WHERE m.sender = ?
) AS d
    LEFT JOIN user AS u 
        ON u.id = d.other_id
    LEFT JOIN avatars AS a
        ON a.id = u.avatarId
WHERE UNIX_TIMESTAMP(timestamp) > ?
ORDER BY m.timestamp ASC
LIMIT 100
```

Answer (score 0):

How about something like:

```
SELECT isself, other_id, u.displayName AS other_name, a.url AS other_avatar, text
FROM
(
    SELECT 0 AS isself, m.sender AS other_id, m.timestamp, m.text
    FROM messages AS m
    WHERE m.recipient = ?

    UNION

    SELECT 1 AS isself, m.recipient AS other_id, m.timestamp, m.text
    FROM messages AS m
    WHERE m.sender = ?
) AS d
    LEFT JOIN user AS u 
        ON u.id = d.other_id
    LEFT JOIN avatars AS a
        ON a.id = u.avatarId
WHERE UNIX_TIMESTAMP(timestamp) > ?
LIMIT 100
```

If the message's sender and recipient IDs will always be found in the user table, the "LEFT JOIN user" should be changed to an inner join--"JOIN user". If each user has an avatar entry, then that left join should also be changed to an inner join.

Comment: I edited the query a bit to actually work (isself = 0 doesn't work for example), I accepted your answer and reflected the changes in here. Thanks!

Comment: Good catch! I'm used to MS SQL Server's syntax which is more flexible as far as "alias = column" syntax. I've edited the above query in several places to reflect MySQL's column alias syntax.